# Putting 2 Views into 1 View in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have View1 and it's got `BreakfastID, Eggs, Toast` for it's columns and View2 has the samething, but I want to combine them so that it looks like this: `BreakfastID, Eggs, Eggs2, Toast, Toast2` is there an easy way?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: it's not the exact same question, fairly identical. I guess we could say I wasn't sure what I was looking for until I asked that other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Day database work is in MySQL so the syntax may reflect that, but the concept should be the same.

In order to select from multiple views or tables with overlapping column names you need to make use of the AS Keyword to rename the overlapping variables, and the table.column syntax to specify what table you're selecting from.

In your case:

```
SELECT View1.BreakfastID AS BreakfastID, View1.Eggs AS Eggs, View2.Eggs AS Eggs2, View1.Toast AS Toast, View2.Toast AS Toast2 FROM View1, View2
```